# I can't compile a C++ program with the g++ command

Tags: compiling, c++, g++, compiler

If I try compiling my C++ source file by the following command:

```
g++ a.cpp
```

it outputs:

```
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium builder

try:
sudo apt-get intsall <<a>selected package>
```

However, if I run the suggested command (`sudo apt-get install g++`), it shows that everything is already installed.

So, basically, how do I compile a simple C++ program in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: What is the output of `which g++`? This sounds like g++ is not in your path.

Comment: Did you install `build-essential`? `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`